# Is it correct to say "We [...] will be present at <destiny> at <time> [...]"?

Tags: grammar, phrases

I am writting an email in English for a website.

As you can see, my English isn't quite perfect.

And one of the emails must be saying something similar to:

```
We confirm that we will be present at <destiny> at <time> to pick you up.
```

Is this the right way to say it?

Saying `at` twice sounds..... wrong and awful.

Comment: I think by "destiny" he means "destination".

Comment: Saying "at" twice is fine here.

Comment: @GEdgar Yeah, I meant "destination". Sorry about that. I needed a small word to fit in the title.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds fine to me.  If the destination is something that requires 'at' [e.g. 'AT the airport", rather than "IN the theatre"] you don't really have a choice.

Comment: I agree with you, but it sounds so painful! And one of the places (that goes where `<desteny>` is) is actually an airport.

Comment: Would `at <destiny> by <time>` be correct, in this case?

Comment: Yes, though technically "by 2 pm" means "at OR BEFORE 2 pm".  It probably doesn't matter here, if you're concerned about repeating "at".

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help. In this case, using `by` won't be that bad since it implies before. It means that there is someone already waiting for them, instead of the other way around.